# MX record for domain and subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, mx-record

Is it possible to setup a MX record for *example.com* and *a.example.com* on the same DNS server in the same zone and is this a good practice?

Some like this:

```
example.com.   IN  A   10.24.233.214
a.example.com. IN  A   10.24.233.289
   
example.com.   IN  MX  10 example.com.
a.example.com. IN  MX  10 a.example.com.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and if you don't have other needs to delegate subdomain to its own zone, it's a good practice.

But, your particular example is useless. The mail is delivered to address under `A` record if `MX` doesn't exist as a fallback, so in your case you if you remove both `MX` records everything will work the same.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering. You have actually answered another question i needed to know. I try to configure an A record and then test.